# FileUpload.FileBytes get OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, out-of-memory

I use FileUpload component. I add file approximately 120mb. But when file size increase, FileBytes get error `OutOfMemoryException`

FileBytes returns byte[].

My code:

```
   byte[] byt = new byte[0];
    byt = FileUpload1.FileBytes;
```

I need to get file and convert byte array or I can use js. 
I must get file. But I take file path. Return value is c:/fakepath.... is wrong.

Any solutions?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. We can't answer from the small amount of code you've provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your web.config, you have two parameters to deal with this:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="X" executionTimeout="Y"/>  
</system.web>
```

(X in kilobytes, Y in seconds)

and

```
<system.webServer> 
     <security> 
          <requestFiltering> 
             <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="Z" /> 
          </requestFiltering> 
     </security> 
</system.webServer>
```

(Z in bytes)